# Send TXT file from Telegram Bot bypassing limitation

Tags: php, telegram, webhooks, telegram-bot

How i send a TXT file from my telegram bot?
I know there is a limitation and work only gif, pdf and zip files but there is a way to bypass this limitation?

```
function sd($chatId){
    $url = $GLOBALS["website"]."/sendDocument?chat_id=".$chatId."&document=https://website.com/file.txt";
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Comment: not sure, but you can zip txt file and share

Comment: Thanks, I had already thought about it, but I would like to send the file directly.

Comment: Did you try renaming the file to the "allowed" fileformats? Example : ..txt -> .gif

Comment: Yes, but I would like it to open immediately, if I put it in an incorrect extension, the phone try to open it with the wrong program and it does not work.